# Asking a question on the degree to which a medium is digital or analog

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I have run across an interesting article in my internet travels [Analog is Not the Opposite of Digital](http://fringefocus.com/2010/technical/analog-is-not-the-opposite-of-digital) which addresses using the term "analog" for a film camera.

I tend to disagree with the article, and I would like to ask a question about the characteristics of traditional film that would make it an analog medium (i.e., able to respond to a virtually continuous spectrum of light, etc.), so it feels like a signal processing question at its core, but I'm not absolutely sure it fits here.  Photography.SE might seem like an obvious choice, but I think that the theoretical perspective/expertise here is more what I am looking for.

I would make every attempt to avoid it being "discussion"y as well, so I think it's safe to assume that it would pass the fundamental test of being a real or constructive question.

Comment: Since you didn't get a response yet, I'd say go ahead and ask and we'll see what people think.

Comment: @yoda Thanks, for some reason I didn't get an inbox notification of your comment.  Oh well, Happy New Year!